# Exception is not handled in PL/SQL function Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have written the following PL/SQL function which returns how long the procedure takes. The function compiled successfully and updates the salary for an employee as expected.

I also wanted to handle an exception if wrong arguments are provided to the function. However if I enter non-existing employee id the exception is not handled the way I tried to do that in the function. And I'm getting a standard Error report.

Another problem is that when the function updates salary successfully I don't see the returned value for INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND.

What can I do to see my custom error message with 'An ERROR Was encountered' string and the returned value?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function myfunction1(e_empno_in IN NUMBER, e_sal_in IN NUMBER)

RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
IS 
e_empno emp.empno%TYPE := e_empno_in;
e_sal emp.sal%TYPE := e_sal_in;

thestart TIMESTAMP;
stopwatch INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;

BEGIN
    SELECT current_timestamp INTO thestart FROM dual;
    UPDATE emp SET sal = e_sal WHERE empno = e_empno;
    SELECT current_timestamp-thestart INTO stopwatch FROM dual;
RETURN stopwatch;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS 
THEN
dbms_output.put_line('An ERROR Was encountered' || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack());
RAISE; 
END;

BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line(myfunction1(7654, 2559));
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NO_DATA_FOUND` is only ever raised when a `select` in an implicit cursor fails to return any rows. when `update`, `delete`, or `insert` fail to find a row, Oracle does not treat that as an error.

To make your code perform as desired, you'll need to test `sql%rowcount` after the `update`, then raise an error yourself.

```
BEGIN
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP INTO thestart FROM DUAL;

    UPDATE emp
    SET    sal = e_sal
    WHERE  empno = e_empno;

    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
        raise_application_error (-20001, 'No row found for id ' || e_empno);
    END IF;

    stopwatch := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - thestart;

    RETURN stopwatch;
END;
```

---

**Other Notes**

- You're typically much better off just letting your custom error propagate, rather than sending it to `DBMS_OUTPUT`. An unhandled error is harder to ignore.
- Since you've designed this as a function, the right way to get the `stopwatch` value you're returning is to handle it in whatever is calling the function.

Comment: Why not `thestart := SYSTIMESTAMP;` etc?

Comment: Thank you it helped. But I had to change the error number since I got Error report -
ORA-21000: "error number argument to raise_application_error of -10001 is out of range". And I stil do not understand how to get the returned stopwatch to be printed out?

Comment: @samba yes, exchange `-10001` with `-20101` as an example. Since userly defined error numbers range `-20000` and `-20999`.